# wsdl2java - WARNING: Default key managers cannot be initialized

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

While generating java WSDL client I am receiving these errors. Can you please help me to understand these?

**C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\apache-cxf-3.0.2\bin>** wsdl2java https://example.com/V1/HelpService?wsdl

*Nov 03, 2014 1:11:20 PM org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.SSLUtils getDefaultKeyStoreManagers
WARNING: Default key managers cannot be initialized: C:\Users\Administrator.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)

Nov 03, 2014 1:11:20 PM org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.SSLUtils getDefaultKeyStoreManagers
WARNING: Default key managers cannot be initialized: C:\Users\Administrator.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)

Nov 03, 2014 1:11:21 PM org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.SSLUtils getDefaultKeyStoreManagers
WARNING: Default key managers cannot be initialized: C:\Users\Administrator.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)*

**C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\apache-cxf-3.0.2\bin>**

Comment: So did you find any solution on this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the property **javax.net.ssl.keyStore** is not specified and if it is not specified .keystore is used in your home directory. If .keystore does not exist you will get this error.

***Snip from org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.SSLUtils.java :***

```
public static String getKeystore(String keyStoreLocation, Logger log)
```

...//some other code

```
keyStoreLocation = SystemPropertyAction.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
if (keyStoreLocation != null) {
    logMsg = "KEY_STORE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_SET";
} else {
keyStoreLocation =
    SystemPropertyAction.getProperty("user.home") + "/.keystore";
    logMsg = "KEY_STORE_NOT_SET";
}
```