# CXF: Default key managers cannot be initialized

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

When I start a webservice soap client using `cxf` and `spring`, I'm getting the following error about 100 times:

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.https.HttpsURLConnectionFactory: Default key managers cannot be initialized: c:\users\me\.keystore (File not found)
```

What does that mean? Where does this error come from?

```
//cxf 3.0.1 autogenerated:
@WebServiceClient
@Generated
public class SoapService extends CXFService {
}

//instantiated by
new SoapService(new SpringBus());
```

/edit: probably duplicate of the following, which has no answers:
[wsdl2java - WARNING: Default key managers cannot be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720402/wsdl2java-warning-default-key-managers-cannot-be-initialized)

Comment: does your wsdl points to SSL address?

Comment: I created an issue and is seems to be a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6094